# CloseHandle() on a job object but not killing a process created by ShellExecute

Tags: c++, createprocess, shellexecute

I have 3 applications, `A.exe`, `B.exe`, and `C.exe`.

`A.exe` creates a job object using this code:

```
CreateJobObject( NULL, NULL);
```

Then it creates a process using this code:

```
CreateProcess(NULL,"B.exe",NULL,NULL,NULL,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB|CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL,NULL,&startupInfo,&processInformation);
```

And finally, it adds the process to the job object.

`B.exe` creates a process for `C.exe` using `ShellExecute()`, just before completing its tasks.

`C.exe` is expected to take 2-3 minutes to complete its task. But as `B.exe` is completed, somehow `C.exe` is also getting killed. I guess because I have used `CloseHandle()` on the job object.

How can I avoid the killing of `C.exe` without a handle leak?

**Update :**
I have used

```
jeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE|JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_DIE_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION;
```

for the job object creation.

Comment: Simply closing a job handle does not kill active processes in the job, unless the job has the `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` flag enabled via `SetInformationJobObject()`. Another option is to change `B.exe` to use `CreateProcess()` instead (which you should do anyway) so you can use its `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/job-objects) for more details.

Comment: yes, I have used jeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE|JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_DIE_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION;

Comment: well, that is important information that should have been included.

Answer (score 0):

The job object needs to be created with additional flag JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK to allow child process to be created outside the job object.

```
jeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE|JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_DIE_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION|JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK;
```

and then rather using

`shellexecute()`

the child process to trigger C.exe needs to be created using CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB as suggested by #Remy Lebeau to start the process outside the job.

`CreateProcess(NULL,"C.exe",NULL,NULL,NULL,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB|CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL,NULL,&startupInfo,&processInformation);`

and then to avoid handle leak used

```
CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);
```